# Displaying image laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having an issue with regards to displaying an image.

```
$url = Storage::disk(config("constants.DEFAULT_STORAGE"))->get(config("constants.EMPLOYEES_IMAGES").$form->id.'/'. $form->image->get(0)->path);
<img src="{{ $url }}">
```

After I have done this I'm getting the following...

A�N6��c�QH�a���?4$��3���H�a�c�Dz���QFα���N�}5��Hc�Q?)���˫FN��i0WF?�S�vH s�sE6�8#gϚ��=�Syi ������K�W�c���(�9�i�n��`(2��cȥ4l[��h�*6O�iJ+����(�0�Z\��(�g��R'VC�>($�)0<����\� �ԩ#w�ȧ���!)F�#�@�u0.F(:��v�Y�#��X2L�<�\�.��,�5�e=��q:�Q�I�A��Pu��o�#��I���Tg�ڹ��D�����qi�6�M����ڃZ��{���� Eg�Ո���/���Oբ�Ll�=�A'�0�#�ڝR���`��ڒ&�.N ���A$�f���ýr�f�|�!�>h`m�-��"

Need some assistance.

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: that isn't a URL, `get` returns the file contents

Comment: $url = Storage::disk(config("constants.DEFAULT_STORAGE"))->path(config("constants.EMPLOYEES_IMAGES").$form->id.'/'. $form->image->get(0)->path);   - This doesn't work either. The image isn't coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

`$url = Storage::url(<pathToImage>);`

Otherwise, you may end up with with the actual image (Which is what you have)

Comment: Well the actually image is what I want to display in img . But I'm getting all this gibberish code.

Comment: What you are getting is the string representation of the digital file. All really need is the string url to give to your browser. The browser will handle rendering the digital file. Did you try our suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Storage::url()`.

`$url = Storage::url(config("constants.EMPLOYEES_IMAGES") . $form->id . '/' . $form->image->get(0)->path);`

`Storage::url()` is used to get file URL and `Storage::get()` to get file contents.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However this is not what I'm looking. I want to display  the picture but i'm getting all this .....A�N6��c�QH�a���?4$��3���H�a�c�Dz���QFα���N�}5��Hc�Q?)���˫FN��i0WF?�S�vH s�sE6�8\#gϚ��=�Syi ������K�W�c���(�9�i�n��`(2��cȥ4l[��h�*6O�iJ+����(�0�Z\��(�g��R'VC�>($�)0<����\� �ԩ#w�ȧ���!)F�#�@�u0.F(:��v�Y�#��X2L�<�\�.��,�5�e=��q:�Q�I�A��Pu��o�#��I���Tg�ڹ��D�����qi�6�M����ڃZ��{���� Eg�Ո���/���Oբ�